# Center relative content inside an absolute-positioned div

Tags: html, css, center

The website I'm working on has a `fixed: 320px;` sidebar on the left, and I would like the rest of the page to be a div containing centered content.

I found a way to center simple content like text: my right `div` has an absolute position, and `right:0;` + `text-align: center;` effectively center its content. But whenever I try to put relative-positioned content in it, it doesn't work anymore.

The relative content I try to center is a responsive gallery, with captions on hover.

Here is [what it looks like](http://thomasiturralde.fr/test)

HTML:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jean Iturralde</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Portfolio de Jean Iturralde"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.backstretch("img/wooden.png");
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="sidebar">
    <header>
        <h1><a href="#">Jean Iturralde</a></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>

    <div id="circle_pic">
        <div id="circle_pic_hover"><p>Jean<br />62 ans<br />Peintre<br /></p></div>
    </div>

    <section>
        <div class="sidebar_title"><img src="img/quotes.png" class="icon" /><h2>Bienvenue,</h2></div>
        <p class="main_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vitae magna quam, commodo vulputate nulla. Mauris fringilla mi sapien, in semper turpis. Aliquam consequat magna nec magna egestas vitae aliquet turpis lacinia. Praesent commodo commodo scelerisque. Maecenas dui urna, egestas vel commodo quis, adipisci.</p>
    </section>

    <footer>
       <p>
        Jean Iturralde<br />
        Tous droits réservés<br />
        Création : <a href="http://thomasiturralde.fr">Thomas Iturralde</a>
        </p>
    </footer>

</div>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="content">
    <p>simple content works</p>
    <div class="box"> <!-- relative content doesn't -->
        <a href="#"><div class="boxcontent">
            <img src="img/tableau_1.jpg">
            <div class="meta">
                <h2>Tableau 1<h2>
                <h3>2013 - Acryllique - 81x65 cm</h3>
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans500';
    src: url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/museo_sans_500-webfont.svg#museo_sans500') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
    margin:0;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:720px;
    background-color:white;
    padding:15px 30px 0 30px;
    width:260px;
    text-align:center;
}

header h1{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

header h1 a{
    color:#303030;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
}

header ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
}

header li a{
    float:left;
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
    font-size:15px;
    color:#afafaf;
    transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -o-transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms;
    border-top:solid 7px #ababab;
    padding:8px 8px 0 8px;
}

header li a:hover{
    color:black;
    border-top:solid 7px #303030;
}

header li a.active{
    color:black;
    border-top:solid 7px #303030;
}

#circle_pic{
    width:174px; height:174px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 87px; -moz-border-radius: 87px;
    background:url(img/profilepic.png) no-repeat;
    margin:70px 0 20px 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#circle_pic_hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:auto; height:175px;
    margin-top:175px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}

#circle_pic_hover p{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:27px;
    margin-top:45px;

}


#circle_pic:hover #circle_pic_hover{
    margin-top:0;
}

section{
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.sidebar_title{
    text-align:left;
}

.icon{
    margin-bottom:-2px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:inline;
    height:30px;
}

#sidebar h2{
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    font-size:29px;
    color:#d9d9d9;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
}

.main_text{
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
    color:#252525;
    margin-top:0;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:25px;
}

footer {
    width:260px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    bottom:5px;
    margin-left:-130px;
}

footer p{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
    color:#959595;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

footer a{
    color:#353535;
}

#wrap{
    position:absolute;
    left:320px;
    top:30px;
    right:0;
}

#content{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

/*******/

.box{
    position:relative;
    width:24%;
    padding-bottom:31%;
    float:left;
}

.boxcontent{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.boxcontent img{
    width:100%;
}

.boxcontent .meta{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom:-52px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    font-family:'museo_sans500';
}

.meta h2,h3{
    color:#b0b0b0;
    margin:0;
}

.meta h2{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.meta h3{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
}

.boxcontent:hover .meta{
    margin-bottom:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .box {
      width: 76%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }

   #sidebar{
    width:100%;
    min-height:0;
    height:120px;
    min-width:0;
    z-index:1;
   }

   #circle_pic, section, footer{
    display:none;
   }

   #content{
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-top:160px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 76%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1390px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box {
      width: 38%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
```

Maybe I should try to change my whole gallery code. But it probably won't be possible to find an equivalent solution including static positioning, right?

(I know that my media-queries settings are totally messed-up, that's an issue I will deal with later.)

Comment: I can't currently reproduce your site. But maybe this article can help you http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your image in a `.box` div, which has `float:left` set in css.

Create another box class (for example, `box-inline`):

```
.box-inline{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; // use this, to make the div behave like it would be part of the text, and it will be automatically aligned.
    width:24%;
    padding-bottom:31%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way I could make the gallery centered, as a block, but not the pictures ? I updated the website : I would like the pictures of the second row to begin at the left.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what would you like to achieve, can you show me that?

I also recommend, to ask this as a different question, so other people can see it, and provide solutions.